# stuck with mastodon services

Tags: ruby, hadoop-yarn, mastodon

I'm trying to get a working install of mastodon but get stuck with web services start.
I've tried a lot of settings and still the 3 mastodon services don't start.
I think there is something wrong with my ruby install and yarn which can't use the --lockfiles option.
I give you the terminal output. please let me know if you have any suggestion to solve this.
[the terminal output errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MqzN.png)

Comment: I have solved the problem for the webservice and sidekiq. i have updated my rubygems version which was 2.7.6 to 3.2.3 (Your RubyGems version (2.7.6) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler.). Now i have to enable the streaming service, seems like it's dealing with node and some other module...

Comment: It seems like my module is missing or I have a wrong user or path...
```Cannot find module '/home/mir7426/streaming'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

Comment: So i have several services down on one hand because i'm installing on mint 19 and debian 11. debian 11 mastodon setting is almost active, i 've generated too much certificate with cerbot so can 't install a new one until 7 days passed. but all mastodon services are active. on mint 19 nginx have two server setting and one thing i didn't know is that http2 is set for ipv6 so if you're using ssl on https (ipv4) you must activate the 443 port on the first server. yarn install doesn't need the lockfile option anymore. using rvm to set ruby version seems to be a good choice. i keep working on it...

Comment: finally i get ngnix start on debian installation some server and firewall configuration did the trick...
```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server http2;
  server_name mydomain.org;
  root /home/mastodon/live/public;
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { allow all; }
  location / { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
#listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name mydomain.org;
```
nevertheless i have a blank page on local and distant adress.otherwise the mastodon icon is showing.